# Sameperiodlastyear for YTD DAX

Tags: dax

I have a measure that shows the Last year value of SalesAmount, right now the LY value is showing a sum of all months in 2022, so this years value is from jan-aug 2023 but LY values is from jan-dec 2022.
Im using this dax: calculate(sum(Invoice[SalesAmount]),all(Dates[Year]), SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR(Dates[FullDateKey]))

How can i make sure that the last year values(2022) only include the months that have passed this year(2023)?

I thought this should be easy but i really can´t get it right..

[image]

1_LYTest = calculate(sum(Invoice[LineTotal]), all(Datedimension[Year]),  SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR(DateDimension[Date]))

[image]

Comment: Its not marked as a date table, i added pictures in the question :)

Comment: You need to get rid of the bridge table. In the invoice table, add a date field for year-month-day, where day is the first or the last day of the month. Then connect your date table to this field with a regular one-to-many relation, and remove the bridge. Your DAX will be much simpler and faster.

Comment: There's a really good video by Alberto Ferrari on YouTube covering exactly this question. Maybe 15 minutes long. https://youtu.be/bAOs5LTP0I0?si=5V8_UEptthZbgC0A

Comment: The video by Albero was exactly what i needed! Thank you!